# Clojure/Java error when connecting to REPL - java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate 'clojure/core/server__init.class

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, clojure-java-interop, clojure-repl

I am on Windows 10.
I succeed to compile and run this jar.
But when I try to connect to Socket REPL from telnet I get this error and telnet wrote `Connection closed by foreign host.`

**ERROR**

```
Exception in thread "Clojure Connection mine 1" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate 'clojure/core/server__init.class or 'clojure/core/server.clj on classpath.
```

Could you please explain what is wrong? :(

```
package com.echo;

import clojure.java.api.Clojure;
import clojure.lang.IFn;
import clojure.lang.RT;
import clojure.lang.Var;
import clojure.lang.Symbol;

public class Echo {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    try {
        IFn plus = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "+");

        System.out.println( plus.invoke(1, 2).getClass().getSimpleName() );

        IFn require = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "require");
        require.invoke(Clojure.read("clojure.core.server"));

        IFn startServer = Clojure.var("clojure.core.server","start-server");
        //Object options = Clojure.read("\"{:port 4555 :accept 'clojure.core.server/repl :name :repl2 :server-daemon false}\"");

        startServer.invoke(
            Clojure.read("{:port 4555 :accept 'clojure.core.server/repl :name mine :server-daemon false}")
        );

        System.out.println( "Started" );


    }
    catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(  e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

}
```

I run like this
`java -cp ".\target\echo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\lib\ext\clojure-1.8.0.jar"  com.echo.Echo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't quote a symbol that you're reading from a string: use `clojure.core.server/repl` instead of `'clojure.core.server/repl`. Quoting is used to prevent evaluation; but since you are not evaluating, this just results in an extra quote thrown in where it doesn't belong.

Comment: Ahh! Thanks a lot!